# jquery text search

Tags: jquery, search, text

I have HTML.

```
<body>
    <span>
        <font="color">
          adfadf
          23423423423
          ORDER_NUMBER:
        </font>
    </span>
    <span>M123456JK98766</span>
</body>
```

M123456JK98766 is 14 digit number. Need to check only 14 digit character.

I like to find a order number M123456JK98766 from HTML. How can I retrieve that? that number can be changed every time by using page refresh.

I have no option to add id against M123456JK98766.

Comment: this is different question having html component

Comment: yeah, I thought I saw this question earlier.

Comment: this is different , pls give me regular expression jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var orderNumber = $('span:contains("ORDER_NUMBER")').next().text();
```

test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/GmENT/4/

Answer (score 0):

There are JS functions such as [match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) and [search()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)but you will still need to be retrieving a chunk of text from an element before you can even do that.